# IOS： [self.tableView reloadData] doestn't reload the data

Tags: ios

I am studying IOS by some tutorial.After I input some text in searchBar and click search, it  send Http Request and parse the JSON data ,then display in tableView,  But when I input some text in searchBar then click search ,the tableView show nothing .while I type anything again in searchBar,the tableView content display.

My question is ,How can I show the content when the first time I click search but not type anything again? Thank you~~
Here is my code :

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

isLoading =YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSURL *url = [self urlWithSearchText: _searchBar.text];
NSString *jsonString = [self performStoreRequestwithUrl:url];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [self parseJSON: jsonString];
[self parseDictionary : dictionary];
[searchResults sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareName:)];
isLoading = NO;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

```
- (NSInteger ) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (isLoading) {
    return 1;
}else if (searchResults == nil) {
    return 0;
}else if([searchResults count] == 0 ){
    return 1;
}else{
    return [searchResults count];
}
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (isLoading) {
    return [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadingCellIdentifier];
}

ResultCell *resultCell =(ResultCell *)[self.tableView
                                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"ResultCell"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableCellGradient.png"];
UIImageView *backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
UIImageView *selectedBackView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedTableCellGradient.png"]];

resultCell.backgroundView = backGroundView;
resultCell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackView;


if ([searchResults count]== 0) {
    resultCell.nameLabel.text = @"Nothing Found";
    resultCell.artistLabel.text = @"";
}else{

    SearchResult * result = [searchResults objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    resultCell.nameLabel.text = result.name;
    NSString *kind = [self kindForDisplay:result.kind];
    resultCell.artistLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",result.artistName,
                                   kind];
}

return resultCell;
```

}

Comment: What's going on with "searchResults" before running reloadData? Is the fetch synchronous?

Comment: yes,the searchResults fectch is synchronous by now.